# how to use std::rel_ops to supply comparison operators automatically?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, visual-studio-2012

How do I get operators `>`, `>=`, `<=`, and `!=` from `==` and `<`?

standard header `<utility>` defines a namespace std::rel_ops that defines the above operators in terms of operators `==` and `<`, but I don't know how to use it (coax my code into using such definitions for:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<MyType>);
```

where I have defined non-member operators:

```
bool operator < (const MyType & lhs, const MyType & rhs);
bool operator == (const MyType & lhs, const MyType & rhs);
```

If I `#include <utility>` and specify `using namespace std::rel_ops;` the compiler still complains that `binary '>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'MyType'`..

Comment: How does one say "compiler, please use std::rel_ops for MyType"?

Comment: [`boost::operators`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) ?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe some `using` _declarations_ so it's picked up by _ADL_... It's easier to write those yourself, or if you are lazy you can leverage `Boost.Operators`

Comment: Well, that edit changes the question pretty substantially.

Comment: Maybe the issue is I'm missing is ADL.  Because my operators are non-member..

Comment: I apologize if that edit throws anyone for a loop.  Sometimes it's hard to know how to frame the question to get the response I need.  Hopefully this revised question helps everyone understand what I'm really asking (and thanks to @K-ballo for supplying the std::rel_ops piece!)

Comment: That you wrote there is a `using` _directive_, not a `using` _declaration_. I was thinking something in the lines of `using std::rel_ops::operator!=` and the like. Which would augment the available operators for **every** type in your namespace, as well as other types that have your namespace as an associated namespace. Bottom line: don't do it

Comment: @Robᵩ thanks - that appears to be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd use the [`<boost/operators.hpp>`](http://www.boost.org/libs/utility/operators.htm) header :

```
#include <boost/operators.hpp>

struct S : private boost::totally_ordered<S>
{
  bool operator<(const S&) const { return false; }
  bool operator==(const S&) const { return true; }
};

int main () {
  S s;
  s < s;
  s > s;
  s <= s;
  s >= s;
  s == s;
  s != s;
}
```

---

Or, if you prefer non-member operators:

```
#include <boost/operators.hpp>

struct S : private boost::totally_ordered<S>
{
};

bool operator<(const S&, const S&) { return false; }
bool operator==(const S&, const S&) { return true; }

int main () {
  S s;
  s < s;
  s > s;
  s <= s;
  s >= s;
  s == s;
  s != s;
}
```

Comment: Note:  you could just use boost::totally_ordered<S> instead of the multiple inheritance.  Also, I tend to use private inheritance for this kind of thing.  Finally, I know it is a trivial example, but operator==() should usually return true for stateless types.

Comment: Note: I just checked that it works correctly with non-member operators (which I prefer when possible).

Answer (score 1):

Actually only `<` should suffice. Do it like so:

`a == b` <=> `!(a<b) && !(b<a)`

`a > b`  <=> `b < a`

`a <= b` <=> `!(b<a)`

`a != b` <=> `(a<b) || (b < a)`

And so on for symmetric cases.

Comment: Ah - your answer is better.  Was worried you could not use !, but you did :)

Comment: I know how to do this myself - and they're simple one liners each.  I just have a vague sense that there is a way to ask the standard library to supply those definitions in terms of the two I've already supplied.  Seems silly to need to write the above for every T which defines `operator ==` and `operator <`, no?

Comment: `<` does not suffice. The `==` you implemented actually test for _equivalence_, not _equality_

Answer (score 0):

```
> equals !(<=)
>= equals !(<)
<= equals == or <
!= equals !(==)
```

Something like this?