# Do I need to manually declare >= and <= operators?

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading

If I already have **operator >** and **operator <** defined (and **operator ==**), do I need to define **operator >=** and **operator <=**, or will the compiler declare them for me if I intentionally don't declare them?

Also, if I have **operator ==** defined, will the compiler declare **operator !=** for me?

Comment: If you have `operator<` and `operator==` defined, you could drag in the [`std::rel_ops`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/rel_ops/operator_cmp) namespace to provide the rest of the operators, but this is not really a [good solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225375/idiomatic-use-of-stdrel-ops). [Boost.Operators](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14756785/241631) is the right way to do this.

Comment: Something just doesn't sit right with me using inheritance to save typing a few operators. Would rather add them manually. =)

Comment: deriving from a class that provides the functionality also has great documentation value. It is a primitive form of Concepts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the Compiler won't declare/define any of the operators you did not define manually. However, Boost.Operators might be to your liking - it does exactly what you want the compiler to do.

Comment: Dang. They generate decent default copy-constructors and such. Was hoping for a simple auto-generated *operator!=(other) { return !(*this == other); }*. Oh well, thanks for the answer! Will wait a bit before accepting it.

Comment: +1 the maintainer of Boost.Operators (Daniel Frey) has an uofficial port called [df.operators](https://github.com/d-frey/operators) of that library to C++11 (rvalue overloads and noexcept)

Answer (score 5):

The compiler won't do anything itself for you here, but it's
relatively simple to generate automatically by inheriting from
an appropriate class, something like:

```
template< typename DerivedType >
class ComparisonOperators
{
public:

    friend bool         operator!=( 
                            DerivedType const&  lhs,
                            DerivedType const&  rhs )
    {
        return !(lhs  == rhs);
    }

    friend bool         operator<=( 
                            DerivedType const&  lhs,
                            DerivedType const&  rhs )
    {
        return !(rhs < lhs);
    }

    friend bool         operator>( 
                            DerivedType const&  lhs,
                            DerivedType const&  rhs )
    {
        return rhs < lhs;
    }

    friend bool         operator>=( 
                            DerivedType const&  lhs,
                            DerivedType const&  rhs )
    {
        return !(lhs < rhs);
    }

protected:
                        ~ComparisonOperators() {}
} ;
```

Define `<` and `==` in your class, and derive from this, and
you'll get all of the operators:

```
class MyClass : public ComparisonOperators<MyClass>
{
    //  ...
public:
    bool operator==( MyClass const& other ) const;
    bool operator<( MyClass const& other ) const;
    //  ...
};
```

Just a note: I've manually simplified the version I actual use,
which defines `==` and `<` as well, looks for the member
functions `compare` and `isEqual`, and uses `compare` for `==`
and `!=` when there is no `isEqual`.  I don't think I've
introduced any errors, but you never know.

Comment: I tend to prefer a `int compare(DerivedType const &o)` which returns a negative, positive, or 0 value (traditional C approach). Usually `==` and `<` are very similar code so it's nice to merge them.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what Boost.Operators already does for you? ;-)

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y Yes.  That's the signature for `compare`, above.  The rule is: only comparisons for equality: `isEqual` (and the relational operators will fail to compile if they're used); equality and relational, use `compare`; _if_ equality can be done much faster, then you can provide both.  And there's a bit of meta programming in the `ComparisonOperators` class which will call the right one.

Comment: For the version I posted, yes; for the version I actually use, no.  But I was unaware of the existance of Boost operators; my actual class pre-dates Boost, and does something more.  (My solution also works with just one class: you don't have to distinguish between `less_than_comparable` and `equality_comparable`.  I don't know whether that is an advantage or a disadvantage.)

Answer (score 0):

There are already some good answers here using `boost` and inheritance. But as someone noted - using inheritance for operator creation seems... wrong.

I know `#define`s are "taboo" in C++, but still that's what I use here.

I have a `#define` in my general utility include that goes like this:

```
#define CREATE_COMPARITORS(name)                              \
inline bool operator>(const name &o){return o<*this;}         \
inline bool operator<=(const name &o){return not (o<*this);}  \
inline bool operator>=(const name &o){return not (*this<o);}  \
inline bool operator!=(const name &o){return not (*this==o);}
```

Then if I have a class, all I need to declare is `operator<` and `operator==`:

```
class ttt{
  //...
  bool operator<(const ttt &o);
  bool operator==(const ttt &o);
  CREATE_COMPARITORS(ttt);
  //...
};
```

Comment: You might need to justify that "seems... wrong." As of now I trust the boost library designers more than your unjustified opinion.

Comment: Was quoting someone else in this thread who said "Something just doesn't sit right with me using inheritance to save typing a few operators". Now, if you want to downvote me because my answer was unhelpful or didn't add anything then fine. But if you downvote me just because I am one of a large group of people who don't like `Boost` and how it does things, while you happen to be part of another group who do like `Boost`, then you're abusing your power.

Comment: -1 for recommending using #define over inheritance, with no justification for what's wrong with inheritance or why this code is exempt from the usual problems with macros.

Comment: Boost does all kinds of things that are abusive of the language, to implement *features* that aren't already present, as a testbed for the features later getting standardized. Boost is very well designed, but sometimes has to use hacks to get code working because of the language limitations. Whether inheriting functionality is wrong or not isn't a big issue, but saying, 'Boost does it, so it must be a good practice' isn't necessarily true. I like Boost alot! The people who design it are very intelligent and better programmers than I. But that doesn't make it good practice.

Comment: Oh, also, [boost uses macroes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html) too. Since Boost uses it, they must be good! =P *deliberately tongue in cheek jab at @djechlin* (just to try to lighten the mood, not actually advocating, or bashing, the use of macroes). Not intentionally bashing djechlin either. =)

Comment: @JaminGrey that's a good point regarding Boost's conscientious use of abuse of language features I hadn't considered. Downvote otherwise stands.